# Commands to Upgrade Kernel on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, kernel, linux-kernel

My current kernel is 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64. I got to know about this by using the command `uname -r`. Now I want to upgrade my kernel version to  3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64.

I used the below blog to upgrade my kernel

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-kernel-in-centos-7-server/

But the kernel got updated to 5.5.2-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64

I need specific version of 3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64.

Could anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance,

Subu Josh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You enabled a third-party repository that supplied a recent, mainline kernel version. While that might work for you, it is not what you wanted.

`yum remove` the packages for the elrepo configuration and its kernel.  `yum upgrade` to apply updates from CentOS.  Reboot to test.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help,

I updated my system and rebooted it after that I got the same kernel version that I wanted.

Thank you so much.